# FullCalendar events not displaying if start date is prior to today, yet event spans into the future

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

Hi FullCalendar peeps.

We are having a problem with our integration of FullCalendar and FullCalendar Scheduler:

- https://fullcalendar.io/
- https://fullcalendar.io/docs/scheduler/

We are using the calendar to build a reservation system where people can book rooms.  The problem arises when there is a reservation that starts in the past, includes today, and then the checkout is in the future.

Let's say today is 7/19/2017 and the reservation is from 7/16/2017 to 7/22/2017.

When we load any view (timelineDay, timelineWeek, timeline2Week) we are not seeing events that exist in the data if they 'span' today (current day).

**FullCalendar JS on page**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',

    ///// Options
    editable: true,
    height: 'auto',
    header: {
      left: 'today prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'timelineDay,timelineWeek,timeline2Week,timelineMonth,timelineYear'
    },
    allDayDefault: true,
    eventOverlap: false,
    navLinks: true,
    resourceAreaWidth: '15%',
    resourceLabelText: 'Rooms',

    ///// Creates views to use.
    views: {
      timelineDay: {
        slotDuration: {days: 1}
      },
      timelineWeek: {
        slotDuration: {days: 1}
      },
      timeline2Week: {
       type: 'timelineWeek',
       duration: { days: 14 },
       slotDuration: {days: 1}
     }
    },
    defaultView: 'timeline2Week',

    ///// Collection of Rooms
    resources: '{{route('api.rooms')}}',

    ///// Collection of Reservations
    events: '{{route('api.calendar')}}',

    ///// Creates popover of reservation info.
    eventRender: function(event,element) {
      $(element).popover({
        title: function() {
          return "<strong>" + event.full_name + "</strong>";
        },
        placement: 'auto',
        html: true,
        trigger: 'hover',
        animation: 'true',
        content: function() {
          return "<p># Guests: <strong>" + event.guest_count + "</strong><br>Total: <strong>" + event.total + "</strong><br>Paid: <strong class=\"at-lime\">" + event.paid + "</strong><br>Owes: <strong class=\"at-orange\">" + event.owes + "</strong><br>Check In: <strong>" + event.checkin + "</strong><br>Check Out: <strong>" + event.checkout + "</strong></p>"
        },
        container: 'body'
      }).popover('show');
      $('.popover.in').remove();
      if(event.lock_room == 1){          
        element.find(".fc-title").prepend("<i class='fa fa-lock'></i> ");
      }
    },

    ///// Select a date range to start a new reservation.
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    selectOverlap: false,
    select: function(start, end, jsEvent, view, resourceObj) {
      // Set checkin date
      var checkin = start.format();
      // Set checkout date
      var checkout = end.format();  
      // alert('Checkin: ' + checkin + ' :: Checkout: ' + checkout);
      // Set room_id
      var room_id = resourceObj.id;
      // Create url to new reservatin page
      var url = "{{ route('reservations.create') }}?room_id=" + room_id + "&checkin=" + checkin + "&checkout=" + checkout + "";
      // Send to new reservation page
      window.location.href = url;
    },
  });
});
```

**Sample from Events Feed**
This sample includes one reservation (id: 10) that has reserved three different rooms (resourceId: 1, resourceId: 8, resourceId: 5).

```
    {
        "id": 10,
        "resourceId": 1,
        "start": "2017-07-16",
        "end": "2017-07-22",
        "title": "Fulchiron, R",
        "guest_count": 4,
        "paid": "$2,655.00",
        "total": "$5,734.80",
        "owes": "$3,079.80",
        "checkin": "Sun, Jul 16th",
        "checkout": "Sat, Jul 22nd",
        "full_name": "Richard Fulchiron",
        "lock_room": 1,
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "resourceId": 8,
        "start": "2017-07-16",
        "end": "2017-07-22",
        "title": "Fulchiron, R",
        "guest_count": 4,
        "paid": "$2,655.00",
        "total": "$5,734.80",
        "owes": "$3,079.80",
        "checkin": "Sun, Jul 16th",
        "checkout": "Sat, Jul 22nd",
        "full_name": "Richard Fulchiron",
        "lock_room": 1,
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "resourceId": 5,
        "start": "2017-07-16",
        "end": "2017-07-22",
        "title": "Fulchiron, R",
        "guest_count": 4,
        "paid": "$2,655.00",
        "total": "$5,734.80",
        "owes": "$3,079.80",
        "checkin": "Sun, Jul 16th",
        "checkout": "Sat, Jul 22nd",
        "full_name": "Richard Fulchiron",
        "lock_room": 1,
    }
```

The Reservation (event) is shown correctly if the start date of the reservation is on the current view as seen here.

[image]

Yet, the Reservation does not show at all if the start date of the reservation is prior to the current view as seen here.

[image]

Since our default calendar load is to show today at the far left of the calendar, we are not seeing current reservations.

I'm sure we are missing some simple setting or overlooked something.  Yet, we can't get to the bottom of it just yet.

Before I create a fiddle, I was wondering if anyone had a quick answer.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have tried to remove all instances of overflow: hidden; and display: none; in all of our css as a first attempt.  This was recommended in other similar posts here on SO.  This did not work.

Comment: Can you verify if the events are actually making it to the browser? They may be getting filtered out by the event feed by start/end date passed to it. When I make feeds my querying is along the lines of where event_end >= view_start (**start** from the url request) && event_start <= view_end (**end** from the url request). Have you tried testing with a hard coded events array with sample data that includes the problematic event and seeing if that works correctly?

Comment: I can't reproduce this using the static events data you provided. Although, you mention that " our default calendar load is to show today at the far left of the calendar". How are you achieving this? That behaviour is not included in the sample code you provided.